# .htaccess 301 redirect 1 folder only

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I'm working on a WordPress site.

I want to 301 redirect all of these links

example.com/**a** > example.com/**b**

example.com/**a**/level1/level2 > example.com/**b**/level1/level2

example.com/**a**/level1/level2/?productid=123 > example.com/**b**/level1/level2/?productid=123

However, I don't want to affect example.com/**c**, example.com/**d**, example.com/**e**, etc.

How would I go about 301 redirecting all of the a traffic to b?

Answer (score 1):

Just place this redirect rule below `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
RewriteEngine ^a(/.*)?$ /b$1 [L,NC,NE,R=301]
```

Query string will be automatically forwarded to new URL.